# spark shuffle partitions to disk

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let us assume I have two pyspark dataframes with three partitions,

```
df1=[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1]]
df2=[[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[1,2,3]]
df1.join(df2,"id").groupby("id").count()
```

I am performing join and group by operations which means it can have two stages.

after the first stage 200 shuffle partitions will be created in my example 3 partitions will be created and rest are empty partitions

the shuffle partitions looks like this

```
partition1 :[1,1,1]
partition2 :[2,2,2]
partition3 :[3,3,3]
```

are these shuffle partitions needs to written to executor disks? so spark in that case is not in-memory computations? why it needs to write the shuffle partitions to the disk? does it use stage1 shuffle partitions in stage 2(group by )?

Answer (score -1):

My initial answer was incorrect. I misread your question, apologies.

You are correct, Spark writes Shuffle results to disk for optimization purposes. Spark computes in memory but stores intermediate results on disk.
It does that, because shuffling is very expensive and you can avoid doing it more often by reusing shuffling results that have been persisted on disk.

This is an example where you can leverage that behaviour:

```
df \
   .join(df2, ["id"]) \
   .join(df3, ["id"]) \
   .join(df4, ["id2"])
```

is faster than

```
df \
   .join(df2, ["id"]) \
   .join(df3, ["id2"]) \
   .join(df4, ["id"])
```

Comment: No problem. so in case of shuffling spark is loosing in-memory computation if I am not wrong. how does the next stage will know it has to pick from disk rather than memory?

Comment: No, the computation happens in memory of course. But the intermediate result is being persisted on disk. I am not a Spark Internal expert but I assume that the next stage knows where to read from through the RDD lineage.

Comment: Shuffle is expensive because of disk writing and network i/o. So what optimization?

Comment: Shuffle is expensive because of network I/O. That's why intermediate results get persisted on disk, so you don't have to reshuffle in case it is still being used